# Google Video Command Line Download

Tags: command-line

Is there a way to download the original (FLV) video files from Google Video from the command line, [just like YouTube?](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/download-youtube-videos-from-command-line-in-ubuntu-linux/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### youtube-dl

The program you linked to already supports this and [is in the Ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/youtube-dl).

Comment: I was not aware this functionality was already present, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[get-flash-videos](http://code.google.com/p/get-flash-videos/)  works rather nice.